# Cómo obtener los documentos de firestore que contengan una keyword Kotlin

Tags: firebase, kotlin, firestore

Dada la siguiente estructura den firestore:

```
Deportes(colección)

        baloncesto(documento)
                 
                     equipos(colección)
                             Los Angeles Lakers(team_name="Los angeles 
                                                lakers",points=2)
                             Chicago bulls
                             Los Angeles Clippers
```

Estoy intentando hacer una petición en la que me obtenga los documentos dada una keyword

```
    fs
.collection("Deportes")
.document("baloncesto")
.collection("equipos")
.whereIn("team_name","Los Angeles"
.get().await()
```

no me obtiene ningún documento, así como si escribo exáctamente el nombre igual entonces sí.

De manera poco elegante estoy obteniendo toda la colección transformando la query a objetos y filtrando la lista con `filter{team-> team.contains(team.team_name)}` pero no hay alguna manera de pedirle a firestore que te devuelva todos los documentos de una colección cuyo field tenga un valor que contenga X parámetro?

mil gracias.

Comment: Para esa consulta particular podrías usar `whereGreaterThanOrEqualTo("team_name","Los Angeles").whereLessThan("team_name","Los Angelet")`. Si en cambio necesitas *full-text search* es recomendable usar [servicios de terceros](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/search?provider=algolia) como menciona la documentación. Es posible hacerlo sólo con firestore pero tendrías que cargar metadata adicional como se ve en [esta](https://youtu.be/4qHXjor3a2E?t=3417) demostración.

Comment: acabo de ver el vídeo, no es exactamente lo que busco, no lo quiero para una barra de búsqueda, pero me ha aclarado que no admite esa funcionalidad. El whereLessThanOrEqual lo había probado pero hace referencia a la longitud? o al contenido del string? muchas gracias por contestar

Comment: Al contenido. Los ordena alfabéticamente y devuelve los que estén dentro del rango delimitado por los operadores, por eso debes usar ambos (`whereGreaterThan` y `whereLessThan`). Pero este método no te servirá si necesitas buscar palabras en medio del texto.

Comment: la verdad que no, ya había probado, pero no sabía bien bien cómo funcionaba, gracias por aclarármelo, la idea original, es que al disparar el evento trajera con la input del usuario, todo documento que contenga parte o todo el contenido del string de una variable, pero me temo que lo más cómodo que puedo hacer es lo que mencioné arriba, bajarme la colección y filtrarla una vez recibida, o se te ocurre algo más óptimo sin recurrir a sistemas de terceros? muchas gracias por interesarte

Comment: No, firestore no tiene esa funcionalidad. Como desarrollador debes saber elegir las herramientas que mejor se adecuen a tu proyecto. Tu has hecho lo contrario. Elegiste una herramienta que no tiene la funcionalidad que necesitas y ahora intentas hackearla para que haga algo para lo que no fue diseñada. Es decir que tienes 3 opciones: cambiar de base de datos, usar servicios de terceros, o seguir con tu solución actual. Sólo puedo decirte que traer la colección completa probablemente sea la opción más costosa.

Comment: gracias por el consejo, soy muy novato he pecado de no documentarme lo suficiente.

Answer (score 0):

Bien como bien me explicó Sinner Firestore no tiene esta consulta, después de pelearme bastante, no sé si será lo óptimo pero si he conseguido que funcione como quiero sin bajar la colección entera.

```
db
.collection(nameOfCollection)
.orderBy(fieldValue)
.startAt(inputStringValue)
.endAt(s+ "\uf8ff")
.get()
.await().toObjects(myObject::class.java)
```

Comment: Esta es la misma opción que te di en el primer comentario, traer los resultados que comiencen con el input. Pero no responde la pregunta de cómo obtener los documentos **contengan** una keyword

Comment: toda la razón, expresé mal y entendí mal, con esto me sirve, pero la pregunta además de estar mal formulada no super ver que necesidad tenía. Recién empiezo a programar y ando un poco perdido. Muchas gracias!!